# How can I download an iOS app/files from xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am a total beginner to swift and iOS. However, I want to create a simple app for iOS. I don't want to publish it though, I want to send the code/app through WhatsApp to someone else. As a present. A nerd present lol.

My question is, how can I download the app from xcode (to an Andriod phone? It doesn't need to work, the phone just has to send the files) and send it via WhatsApp to someone else. Would that work? And how could the receiver use the app?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You want to use your app on an android?

Comment: No, the android would just send the app. The receiver has an iOS. I just need to get the files on the android and I need to know how the receiver iOS can use the files/app.

Comment: You have an android but your receiver has a IOS device. So you downloaded xcode and want to test it with a android?

Comment: Installing iOS apps is not as simple as that, you'll need to sign your binary with the correct info to install on your friend's device, and even if you do that properly you won't be able to just send the compiled app. You could submit to TestFlight and send them a link, but I think that'll require a paid account. Easiest thing would be to install directly from your computer to their phone.

Comment: For iPhones, you cannot "send apps to people" the way you can for the (wild, wild, west environment) of Android. You need to have an Apple developer account, build your app, then either use TestFlight (register your friend as an internal tester) or register your friend's device for ad-hoc distribution. (Search for `ios ad-hoc distribution`)

Comment: Hi! iOS devices cannot install and run arbitrary apps that were downloaded e.g. from WhatsApp. This is both a security feature and a way for Apple to control their ecosystem. To be able to install and run an app, that app has to be properly signed by an Apple Developer Program member. Once you know how to create signed Ad Hoc builds, you could (theoretically) ask your friend for their device's UDID, register their device as a test device, make the build, upload it to a distribution service like appcenter.ms, invite them to that distribution service, and then share the app build with them.

Comment: None of this is possible without you becoming an Apple Developer Program member, however, and without your friend's prior knowledge and cooperation (as you would need to register their device under your Developer account). Also none of this is particularly easy or straightforward if you're just getting into iOS app development, unfortunately. So I would recommend to focus on building your app in the Xcode Simulator first (which is both easy and free), and then showing them the app running in the simulator on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Apple developer account need for distribute iOS app to particular device/people.

Also need UDID of iOS device.

Build app in Xcode(DemoApp.ipa).

Upload into "https://www.diawi.com/" or "http://www.deployninja.com/"

Share link and install in iOS devices(registered in your developer account: UDID).